# Restrict bandwidth for a MAC ID for certain domains

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, bandwidth

I need to restrict bandwidth (make the site really slow) for 2-3 HTTPS domains (instagram.com and facebook.com) for a relative of mine. So need to target domain and MAC ID of the device.

We have a basic consumer router and WiFi at home which doesn't support such options. It has crude options like bandwidth on all sites for a particular person. One knob for everything. Slowing down all websites would make the concerned person suspicious.

Of course open to buying hardware (Raspberry Pi, a new router etc). If there's any suitable mechanism please do let me know.

> Say there are 10 devices at home A, B, C, D and so on. I want Instagram
>   and Facebook to load extremely slowly on C's device. Every other site
>   should work fine on C's device.

**It's a medical requirement and advice/preaching isn't working. Please don't suggest talking and being honest with the person. I need a tech solution.**

Answer (score 1):

MAC is only available on the **local** network. For all devices outside that it will be sent via the router and show the routers MAC<sup>*1</sup>.

So basically, no, it it not a lack of option on your router. It is simply not part of the spec of IP.<sup>*2</sup>

What you want to ask yourself instead:

1. Does this item belong on the internet or on an intranet?
2. Do I just want to filter websites? (hint: proxy)
3. Firewall settings. Firewall settings. Firewall settings.

---

<sup>*1</sup>Unless you have multiple routes. But then if is the MAC of the relevant router. And that certainly is not a common setup.

<sup>*2</sup>Unless you hack each end computer and tell them to send them your MAC. Which has obvious implications next to the impossibility to pull it off

Comment: Yes. I'm aware that MAC of my router is sent. What I mean is my router has an option to limit bandwidth for particular devices in the house. I need an extra filter as well. Limit speed only for certain devices WHEN trying to access blacklisted sites.

Comment: I was told that Squid Proxy's delay pools don't work on HTTPS sites. To the best of my knowledge Squid Proxy does what I want. Can you please give your thoughts.

Comment: Maybe a weird question: But since info was added, why steer on MAC and not on IP?  MACs can be changed on the device. IP can be changed on the device. Equal sane opportunity. And firewalls et ctend to work on IP level. And as router (and DHCP server) you device which device gets which IP.

Comment: I'm open to both. IP's might change everytime they connect to the WiFi router. He isn't tech saavy enough to spoof MACs hence the preference.